# auto scaling inline-blocks using max and min height not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, grid

I have a layout of inline blocks, where each non fully populated row gets centered in its parent container.
**Edit: I was thinking maybe i could using something like this (but better)(JS):** if if newnoCols > currentnoCols I want the number of columns to be increased by 1, if if newnoCols < currentnoCols I want the number of columns to be decreased by 1 but my code below isnt doing this (not sure how to achieve this).

```
//check if number of images in each row can change when resizing the window
currentnoCols = floor(windowWidth/minImgWidth)

// Function to be executed on window resize
function handleResize() {
//calc number of columns (of width = minImgWidth) that would fit in new window width
    newnoCols = floor(windowWidth/minImgWidth)
    if newnoCols > currentnoCols then imgWidth = minImgWidth
    if newnoCols < currentnoCols then imgWidth = maxImgWidth
    currentnoCols = newnoCols
}

// Attach the resize event listener
window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

// Initial call to handleResize to get initial values
handleResize();
```

**I want the margins on the left and right of the outermost images to remain equal (e.g. 5vw) when resizing the browser window (aka when page width changes)**.
In other words, when the page width is changed, I want the images in the class `container` to automatically scale such that the `margin-left` and `margin-right` is always a fixed value. Once the page is widened to such an extent that an extra `img` of `width=min-width` (as set in style properties of the `img`) can fit within the row, I want the size of the images to be set to `min-width` (such that each fully populated row will host an extra image, which should automatically happen when `img`-width is set to `min-width` given the circumstances). When the page is widened further, I want them to scale to retain the margins (to keep them at the fixed value). The wrapping effect works fine with the current code but images remain a fixed size and setting image size using `min-` and `max-` `height` values does not have the desired effect (`img`'s become full width and height is cropped.

*current result (without using max-/min- height):*
[image]

What am I doing wrong/how may I achieve the desired result?

https://codepen.io/Maarten-Mtr/pen/poqgzWP (PS: for reasons unknown the items on non fully populated rows are not being centered when viewing code result on codepen, they are for me using VScode with live server using firefox browser)

```css
.container {
  width: 95vw;
  text-align: center;
}

.tile {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30vh;
  padding: 1vh;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tile"><img class="popupHanne" src="https://www.firstbenefits.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/placeholder.png" /></div>
  <div class="tile"><img class="popupApeldoorn" src="https://www.firstbenefits.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/placeholder.png" /></div>
  <div class="tile"><img class="popupApeldoorn" src="https://www.firstbenefits.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/placeholder.png" /></div>
  <div class="tile"><img class="popupHanne" src="https://www.firstbenefits.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/placeholder.png" /></div>
  <div class="tile"><img class="popupIjsselmuiden" src="https://www.firstbenefits.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/placeholder.png" /></div>
</div>
```

I tried achieving the desired result using a `max-height` and `min-height` for the image elements whilst setting `width` to `auto` but did not manage to get this working. For some reason the images don't scale uniformly when using min/max height values even though I set `width` to `auto` (I would expect aspect ratio to not change when scaling). Also the items don't wrap to the next line anymore. (for `max-height` and `min-height` for the images, I used `inherit` to prevent the images being cropped in height), as such:

```
.tile {
    display: inline-block;
    max-height:50vh;
    min-height:10vh;
    padding: 1vw;
    width:auto;
  }

  img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    max-height:inherit; min-height:inherit;
  }
```

in other words/in summary:
**I want the `img`'s to automatically wrap to the next column if there isn't enough space for them when resizing, or the other way around (more width--> more images per row).

I want the image size to scale automatically when resizing the page, such that a fixed value is retained for the left and right margin (e.g. `5vw`). I want the size of the images to be set using min- and max- values for example min-and max height such that when resizing the page (making it wider), the images don't get too big.**

Comment: The items on non fully populated rows are not being centered when viewing code result on codepen because you have added a `<style>` tag inside the CSS. which invalidates the `.container` selector.